# Overwrite data coming from source to lakehouse in data fabric

Tags: powerbi, data-lakehouse

My data is coming from a source X. However, everyday the data is getting updated. So when that data is coming to lakehouse in data fabric, it is getting appended everytime. How do I overwrite the old with the new ones and also add new data.

Eg.
This is my data:

[image]

When the value column is updated in source, the entire data is getting appended. Like below:

[image]

However, I want the values to be overwritten like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're writing data to the lakehouse using a notebook in Fabric ? If yes, you should use the `mode("overwrite")` when writing the table : `df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("myTable")`

Comment: I am getting data from a source directly. I am not using notebook. 

Using the pipeline i have connected to the SFTP source and got the data to lakehouse. But in this way my data is getting appended.   @Nikill

Comment: this is not working

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this using only a pipeline, you'll need a notebook or a dataflow to handle appending of new data.